# Difference between Reassignment and Update of argument in Scala

Tags: scala, var

Here is the a peice of code that works fine -

Now my question is - if I declare the argument of `Class Vector` as `val`, and assign a new value to `Vector v1` like `v1(1) = 10` - I have the error as `error: reassignment to val`.

To avoid that I change the argument type `var`from `val` . So far I understand the concept as declaring arguments as `val`, the `Class` becomes immutable and I can't assign a new value to the `val`.

My confusion arises even I declare `var` as the argument type, I still can't update the value of `vector v1` or `v2`. I need to have another `method`, `def update` to update the value of  `Vector v1 or v2`. Why so?

Updating a value is not same as reassignment a value or vice-versa. Without the `def update method` I got the error as `error: value update is not a member of this.Vector`.

What concept I am missing ?

```
class Vector(var x: Double, var y: Double, var z: Double) {
    def +(v: Vector) = new Vector(x+v.x, y+v.y, z+v.z)
    def -(v: Vector) = new Vector(x-v.x, y-v.y, z-v.z)
    def dot(v: Vector) = x*v.x + y*v.y + z*v.z
    def cross(v: Vector) = new Vector(
                            y*v.z - z*v.y, 
                            z*v.z - x*v.z,
                            x*v.y - y*v.x)


    def apply(index: Int): Double = index match {
        case 0 => x
        case 1 => y
        case 2 => z
    }

    def update(index: Int, value: Double): Unit = index match {
        case 0 => x = value
        case 1 => y = value
        case 2 => z = value
    }

    def printForm: String = "("+x+", "+y+", "+z+")"
}

val v1 = new Vector(1,2,4)
val v2 = new Vector(2,3,5)

println("+ " + (v1+v2).printForm)
println("- " + (v1-v2).printForm)

println(v1(0))
v1(1) = 10   
println(v1(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing to realize is `v1(1) = 10` , this is really syntactic sugar for `v1.update(1, 10)`.

This is not just for your type, even [Scala collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashMap@update(key:A,value:B):Unit) work this way.

So when you write `v1(1) = 10`, the compiler is going to complain if you don't have the `update` method defined for your class.

If you just want to be able to update your vectors, there's nothing to stop you from just doing `v1.x = 10`, as long as `x` is declared with `var` and isn't protected or private.